# Почему в Tkinter не работает проверка на пустую строку?

Tags: python, tkinter

Пишу простейшую игру, где есть поле для текста (вопросы) и кнопка. При нажатии на нее в соседнем поле выводится ответ. Действие функции с ответом привязано к кнопке, и без проверки на пустое поле ответ (он рандомно выбирается из списка) все равно выводится.

Мне же надо добиться, чтобы при пустом поле ответ не появлялся, а вместо него печатался призыв все-таки задать свой вопрос.

Реализовал это двумя способами, однако ни один не дал требуемого результата. Все равно при нажатии на кнопку выпадает ответ. Даже при отсутствии напечатанного вопроса. Как быть?

```
# Обработчик вопроса пользователя 
def questionQuery(event):
    question = text_box_question.get('1.0', tk.END) # читаем текст из виджета text_box_question
    time.sleep(2)
    if not question:      # другая реализация - if question=='':                                   
        text_box_answer.insert(tk.END, 'Задайте свой вопрос') 
    else:
        answerQuery()
                    

# Функция возврата случайных ответов
def answerQuery():
    text_box_answer.insert(tk.END, 'Хмм...' + '\n') # и выводим в виджет text_box_answer
    window.update_idletasks()
    time.sleep(2)
    window.after(2000, lambda: text_box_answer.insert(tk.END, random.choice(responses) + '\n'))

# привязываем к кнопке обработку события 
button_ask.bind('<Button>', questionQuery)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас не срабатывает, потому что `text_box_question.get('1.0', tk.END)` вернёт перевод строки `\n` для пустого текста. Проверяйте на пустую строку `question.strip()`.
Пример для теста:

```
import tkinter as tk

def questionQuery():
    question = text_box_question.get('1.0', tk.END) # читаем текст из виджета text_box_question
    text_box_answer.insert(tk.END, f'Question: <{question}>\nAs bytes: <{question.encode()}>\n') 
    if not question.strip():
        text_box_answer.insert(tk.END, 'Задайте свой вопрос\n') 
    else:
        text_box_answer.insert(tk.END, f'Вопрос был: <{question}>') 

root = tk.Tk()
text_box_question = tk.Text(root, height=3)
text_box_question.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
text_box_answer = tk.Text(root, height=10)
text_box_answer.pack(fill=tk.X)
btn = tk.Button(root, text="Press me", command=questionQuery)
btn.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

[image: -]